# Why does cURL not work behind varnish-cache?

Tags: apache, curl, nginx, wget, varnish

Recently, I installed [varnish-cache](https://www.varnish-cache.org/)
on my virtual server because I have two seperated web servers running (Apache2 for my own projects, Nginx because of GitLab and Jenkins internal web server). I configured my web servers to listen on a different port than 80 and told varnish to take port 80. It worked pretty well, but now neither cURL nor wget is working... I hope somebody can help me with this very specific topic, here are my config files:

/etc/default/varnish:

```
# Configuration file for varnish
#
# /etc/init.d/varnish expects the variables $DAEMON_OPTS, $NFILES and $MEMLOCK
# to be set from this shell script fragment.
#
# Note: If systemd is installed, this file is obsolete and ignored.  You will
# need to copy /lib/systemd/system/varnish.service to /etc/systemd/system/ and
# edit that file.

# Should we start varnishd at boot?  Set to "no" to disable.
START=yes

# Maximum number of open files (for ulimit -n)
NFILES=131072

# Maximum locked memory size (for ulimit -l)
# Used for locking the shared memory log in memory.  If you increase log size,
# you need to increase this number as well
MEMLOCK=82000

# Default varnish instance name is the local nodename.  Can be overridden with
# the -n switch, to have more instances on a single server.
# INSTANCE=$(uname -n)

# This file contains 4 alternatives, please use only one.

## Alternative 1, Minimal configuration, no VCL
#
# Listen on port 6081, administration on localhost:6082, and forward to
# content server on localhost:8080.  Use a 1GB fixed-size cache file.
#
# DAEMON_OPTS="-a :6081 \
#              -T localhost:6082 \
#              -b localhost:8080 \
#              -u varnish -g varnish \
#              -S /etc/varnish/secret \
#              -s file,/var/lib/varnish/$INSTANCE/varnish_storage.bin,1G"


## Alternative 2, Configuration with VCL
#
# Listen on port 6081, administration on localhost:6082, and forward to
# one content server selected by the vcl file, based on the request.
# Use a 256MB memory based cache.
#
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,256m"


## Alternative 3, Advanced configuration
#
# See varnishd(1) for more information.
#
# # Main configuration file. You probably want to change it :)
# VARNISH_VCL_CONF=/etc/varnish/default.vcl
#
# # Default address and port to bind to
# # Blank address means all IPv4 and IPv6 interfaces, otherwise specify
# # a host name, an IPv4 dotted quad, or an IPv6 address in brackets.
# VARNISH_LISTEN_ADDRESS=
# VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT=6081
#
# # Telnet admin interface listen address and port
# VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
# VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=6082
#
# # The minimum number of worker threads to start
# VARNISH_MIN_THREADS=1
#
# # The Maximum number of worker threads to start
# VARNISH_MAX_THREADS=1000
#
# # Idle timeout for worker threads
# VARNISH_THREAD_TIMEOUT=120
#
# # Cache file location
# VARNISH_STORAGE_FILE=/var/lib/varnish/$INSTANCE/varnish_storage.bin
#
# # Cache file size: in bytes, optionally using k / M / G / T suffix,
# # or in percentage of available disk space using the % suffix.
# VARNISH_STORAGE_SIZE=1G
#
# # File containing administration secret
# VARNISH_SECRET_FILE=/etc/varnish/secret
#
# # Backend storage specification
# VARNISH_STORAGE="file,${VARNISH_STORAGE_FILE},${VARNISH_STORAGE_SIZE}"
#
# # Default TTL used when the backend does not specify one
# VARNISH_TTL=120
#
# # DAEMON_OPTS is used by the init script.  If you add or remove options, make
# # sure you update this section, too.
# DAEMON_OPTS="-a ${VARNISH_LISTEN_ADDRESS}:${VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT} \
#              -f ${VARNISH_VCL_CONF} \
#              -T ${VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS}:${VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT} \
#              -t ${VARNISH_TTL} \
#              -p thread_pool_min=${VARNISH_MIN_THREADS} \
#              -p thread_pool_max=${VARNISH_MAX_THREADS} \
#              -p thread_pool_timeout=${VARNISH_THREAD_TIMEOUT} \
#              -S ${VARNISH_SECRET_FILE} \
#              -s ${VARNISH_STORAGE}"
#


## Alternative 4, Do It Yourself
#
# DAEMON_OPTS=""
```

/etc/varnish/default.vcl:

```
#
# This is an example VCL file for Varnish.
#
# It does not do anything by default, delegating control to the
# builtin VCL. The builtin VCL is called when there is no explicit
# return statement.
#
# See the VCL chapters in the Users Guide at https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/
# and http://varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExamples for more examples.

# Marker to tell the VCL compiler that this VCL has been adapted to the
# new 4.0 format.
vcl 4.0;

# Default backend definition. Set this to point to your content server.
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8021";
}

backend gitlab {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8022";
}

backend jenkins {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8023";
}


sub vcl_recv {
    # Happens before we check if we have this in cache already.
    #
    # Typically you clean up the request here, removing cookies you don't need,
    # rewriting the request, etc.

    if (req.http.host ~ "git.mydomain.com") {
        set req.backend_hint = gitlab;
    }

    if (req.http.host ~ "ci.mydomain.com") {
        set req.backend_hint = jenkins;
    }


}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    # Happens after we have read the response headers from the backend.
    #
    # Here you clean the response headers, removing silly Set-Cookie headers
    # and other mistakes your backend does.
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # Happens when we have all the pieces we need, and are about to send the
    # response to the client.
    #
    # You can do accounting or modifying the final object here.
}
```

When I try to cURL a domain, I always get the output of my localhost, which is the Apache2 default page (It works ...).

Hopefully, I did not forget anything, so please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: What does you curl command look like?

Comment: `curl http://google.com`
I am using Debian 7.
I think I have to set an environment variable with my proxy settings... But how and with which params?

Comment: Why would `curl http://google.com` hit your server? Are you Google?

Comment: No, but I think this is because of varnish, maybe the request of curl is redirected on my local machine's webserver? And this is not only when trying to get google.com, but also on other websites or hostnames that are not really available as you can see in this picture: [Image](http://prntscr.com/8lssny)